# Enable GNU Fortran 7.xy on CentOS 7.9: scl command not found

Tags: centos, gnu, container, scl

I'm trying to enable GNU Fortran ver 7.xy on a CentOS 7.9 image in a Singularity container. According to various sources on the internet I need to install the following packages with `yum`:

```
yum install centos-release-scl scl-utils-build devtoolset-7-gcc*`
```

After the installation I try to enable this toolchain with

```
scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
```

However, I obtain the error

```
scl: command not found
```

I tried to find `scl`, starting my search from `/`, but it is not found either:

```
sudo find / -name "scl"
```

Also `whereis scl` returns nothing. Did anyone encounter this error before? What would be the remedy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scl` application is delivered with the `scl-utils` package.  The `scl-utils` package should have been installed as a dependency of `devtoolset-7-gcc`.

I think I see what happened though, if you have your full output from when you ran `yum install centos-release-scl scl-utils-build devtoolset-7-gcc*`, you may notice a line `No package devtooset-7-gcc* available`.

This would be due to trying to install an additional repository and a package from that repository at the same time (the other two packages should have installed fine though).  YUM does not work like that, as the new repository metadata would not be built until the next run of YUM and would not be available in the same transaction that installed the repository.

If you separate your install command into two commands, YUM should be able to install the `devtoolset-7-gcc*` packages:

```
yum install centos-release-scl scl-utils-build
yum install devtoolset-7-gcc\*
```